# How to keep section titles in small caps (in the main body) but in the default font in table of contents?

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs

I want to make a book in LaTeX where the section titles are written using `\textsc` in the main body but when it is shown in the table of contents it should be in the default font. Other titles would also have default font.

However, using the following code isn't helping,

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\pagestyle{plain}
\title{Sample Title}
\date{}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks,
citecolor=blue,
filecolor=blue,
linkcolor=blue,
urlcolor=red
}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\KOMAoption{fontsize}{12pt}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\markboth{}
{}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1}
\end{document}
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: If it should be normal in the toc, why are you applyring the font changer to the optional argument (that typesets stuff in the toc)?

Comment: Sections are typeset with a bold font by default in the document. You need a font that supports bold small-caps (which would be overkill) or you have to reset the font-weight.

Comment: You just deleted that part, my comment is now invalid.

Comment: @Johannes_B: I want to write the section titles in small caps only in the main body, not in the toc.

Comment: You should try with the `titlesec` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sectsty`, for example:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
%\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  citecolor=blue,
  filecolor=blue,
  linkcolor=blue,
  urlcolor=red,
}

\sectionfont{\normalsize\normalfont\scshape}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}

\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Alph} % to keep hyperref happy

\title{Sample Title}
\date{}
\maketitle

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1}

\end{document}
```

Note I did some reordering to your code. I'm not sure `scrextend` is useful, but you can judge for yourself.

I'd also avoid `\Large` for section titles in small caps. Maybe loading `microtype` and adding `\lsstyle` would be better.

### TOC

[image]

### First page

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use a package or do it yourself. Below is the default `\section` for `book` with `\scshape` substituted for `\bfseries`:

```
\makeatletter
    \renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                               {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                               {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                               {\normalfont\Large\scshape}}
\makeatother
```